# Optimization/minimization/curve fitting with a non-linear model and imported data

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

Which method can be used to optimize parameters of a model, to fit experimental data?

Concrete: Following parameters and calculation model:

Fixed parameters:

```
P0 = 101325;
Pr = 0.71;
η = 1.838*10^-5;
κ = 1.4;
ρ0 = 1.19;
c0 = (κ*P0/ρ0)^0.5;
Z0 = ρ0*c0;
f = Range[400, 10000]; 
ω = 2*Pi*f;
d := 15*10^-3;
```

Adjustable parameters. Accuracy should be 0.01, except σ (0.1). Range/Boundary conditions are in brackets.

```
ϕ -> [0.5 - 1];
σ -> [5000, 140000];
α -> [1, 4];
λ -> [1*10^-6 , 1*10^-4];
λ' -> [1*10^-6 , 1*10^-4];
kop -> [1*10^-11 , 1*10^-9];
```

Calculation model with formulas:

```
H = (λ^2*σ^2*ϕ^2)/(4*α^2*η*ρ0); 
g = Sqrt[1 + (I*ω)/H]; 
nup = η/(Pr*ρ0); 
Mp = (8*kop)/(λ^2*ϕ); 
wtl = (nup*ϕ)/kop; 
gp = Sqrt[1 + (I*Mp*ω)/(2*wtl)]; 
Reff = α*(1 + (g*(σ*ϕ))/(I*α*ρ0*ω)); 
Keff = κ/(κ - (κ - 1)/(1 - (I*gp*wtl)/ω));
kw = ω*Sqrt[Reff/Keff];
Zc = Sqrt[Reff*Keff];
Zs = -I*Zc*Cot[kw*d];
r = (Zs - 1)/(Zs + 1);
(*Target value a (absorption over frequency f *)
a = 1 - Abs[r]^2;
```

I want to import data like this: (Must the frequency steps be the same as the setps of the range of defined variable `f`?)

[image: Absorption(y-axis) over frequency (x-axis)]

My target is now, to get the adjustable parameters for the best fit to a given plot/imported-data.

Please give concrete answers. Best would be a concrete solution inculdung an optimization model with implemented boundaries. Explanation or suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Have you taken a look at`Fit`, `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: Yes i tried, see edit of the question.

Comment: Rather than edit the question you opened up a duplicate question (although the duplicate is more informative).  So you might want to consider editing this question to look like the newest question so that the good comment by @MauricioLobos that you've used doesn't get lost.  Also, based on your newer question, I don't think there's much additional advice we can give without the data (or a subset of the data).  And it might be that your function just doesn't bend the same way as the data.